# How do I algebriacally analyze these results from the mandlebrot set?

Tags: fractals

The equation for the mandelbrot set is z = z^2 + c,

in my exploration, I changed the values of c and analyzed the iteration in the table below

[image]

What algebriac patterns emerge in this table?

Comment: The equation cited is only part of the definition of the Mandelbrot set, which is: the set of complex $c$ such that the complex series defined by  $z_0=0$, $z_{n+1}={z_n}^2+c$ is bounded as $n$ goes to infinity. By studying only real values of $c$, you are studying only the intersection of that set and the reals. Hint: prove that's a segment, and which.